# Executing Spring boot jar in Amazon EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am new to amazon EC2 instances. I am able to deploy my jar in EC2 linux instance and execute it but the jar is running in Private DNS mode. I am not able to access the http and https urls from my local machine. I already enabled all traffic to access the api (in Security Group). Do I miss anything to get the api access over the internet? How can I run my api in public DNS mode?